# Is FIELD COLLECTION VIEWS module only for showing data in table format?

Tags: entities

I am using [field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module and in search of formatting it I came across [field collection views](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_views) module. But whatever tutorial I came across, in all it is display data in Table form only. Is there possibility that we can use field collection views module as Views module so we can have lots of option for formatting? Or Field collection views module is limited to show data to Table format only?

Answer (score 1):

At admin/structure/types/manage/[node-type]/display/full changed the view mode for my field_collection where format = "Table of field collection items". The view mode setting is ignored, as viewing the original node still shows all fields as configured in the "Full content" display mode.

[field_collection_table.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/field_collection_table-1441668-7.patch)